# Match all from beginning to /aaa-bbb-ccc/, excluding /aaa-bbb-ccc/

Tags: r, regex

Consider the following string:

```
tempo/blah/blah/aaa-bbb-ccc/def/ghi/jkl
```

I have a bunch of strings that have `/aaa-bbb-ccc/` in them. I would like to remove any characters that occur before `/aaa-bbb-ccc/`. The final product of the above, for example, should be `/aaa-bbb-ccc/def/ghi/jkl`.

My attempt, after some searching:

```
x <- "tempo/blah/blah/aaa-bbb-ccc/def/ghi/jkl"
sub("^.*[^/aaa-bbb-ccc/]", "", x)
[1] ""
```

Comment: `[^/aaa-bbb-ccc/]` does not do what you think it does: it matches only the *single characters*  in the class, not the whole string - use a non-capturing group instead. Hence `[^-abc/]` would be the same here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use lazy dot matching and wrap the known value with a capturing group to restore with a backreference later:

```
x <- "tempo/blah/blah/aaa-bbb-ccc/def/ghi/jkl"
sub(".*?(/aaa-bbb-ccc/)", "\\1", x)
## [1] "/aaa-bbb-ccc/def/ghi/jkl"
```

See [this R demo](https://ideone.com/GYW3l2).

See [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Q2sR1p/1), `.*?` matches any 0+ chars, as few as possible, and `(/aaa-bbb-ccc/)` is a capturing group with ID=1 that is reference to with `\1` from the replacement pattern.

Note you may also *extract* that part using `regmatches`/`regexpr`:

```
x <- "tempo/blah/blah/aaa-bbb-ccc/def/ghi/jkl"
regmatches(x, regexpr("/aaa-bbb-ccc/.*", x))
```

See [this R demo](https://ideone.com/3t1NEj). `.*` just grabs any 0+ chars up to the end of the whole character vector.